# Sequential downloading files from internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, download, isolatedstorage

I want to download files from internet upon a button click and save in isolated storage in windows phone. But because i have multiple files to be downloaded from internet, all downloads must be taking place but in sequential manner so that user can see the progress and immediately access them when they are downloaded.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach(string url in urlarray)
{
    DownloadFile(url);
} 
}

void DownloadFile(string url)
{
    WebClient downloadfile = new WebClient();
    downloadfile.OpenReadCompleted += downloadfile_OpenReadCompleted;
    downloadfile.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute)); 
}

void downloadfile_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//Save to isolated storage
}
```

Now if this is the code, isolated storage exception will be thrown. So i wanted to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() but i dont know how to use it. And also i want to download and save without any exceptions. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "isolated storage exception will be thrown"?  Your question would be improved if you added details about the exception and any inner exceptions.

Comment: i have commented as "//Save to isolated storage ".I would be saving to isolated storage.When one file is saving to isolated storage, other file when it completes it download it would also try to store. This cause to raise an isolated storage exception...

Comment: Again, exception type, exception message, inner exception type, message, etc, is much better than trying to describe.  Also, it sounds like the actual code you're using to save the file might be useful, as it seems like you're trying to write to the same file.

Comment: Actually my code is running fine but if the downloads are finished at same time, both the downloaded files compete to get saved in the isolated storage same time.right? then an exception is thrown. Right i don't have any exception. It depends by chance that two files "MAY" conflict. So i want to avoid this approach. That's what i have asked.

Comment: Still having a hard time understanding.  I don't have experience with using iso storage on the phone, so there might be some limitations with using iso storage files asynchronously, but I doubt that.  Maybe someone with more experience in this area will understand better what you're asking.